# How to add decimal separator to a grouped (money like) number?

Tags: c#, format

## Summary

Are `{0:#,##}` and `{0:#,#}` different? I know that the `.` determines the location of the decimal separator in the result string, and the `,` serves as both a group separator and a number scaling specifier. As a group separator, it inserts a localized group separator character between each group. As a number scaling specifier, it divides a number by 1000 for each comma specified.

## Example

Take a look at some examples:

```
original    #,##      #,#
12568    -> 12,568    12,568
12568.12 -> 12,568    12,568
1.12     -> 1         1
.12      -> Error    Error
```

They are all the same even in error.

## Question

Why the decimal part does not appear in the examples? How to add decimal separator to a grouped (money like) number?

Answer (score 3):

See here: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

The problem is in `,`. Your culture decimal separator is `.`, not `,`.

If you replace `,` by `.` you will get:

```
original    #.##       #.#
12568    -> 12568      12568
12568.12 -> 12568.12   12568.1
1.12     -> 1.12       1.1
1.56     -> 1.56       1.6 //new (see rounding)
```

Also, you can pass needed `IFormatProvider` that uses `,` as decimal separator and your example will work with `,`.

So, the difference is visible in the last example - there can be rounding.